# Accessing regmap RegFields

Tags: chisel, rocket-chip

I am trying to find a clean way to access the `regmap` that is used with `*RegisterNode` for creating documentation and testing files. The `TLRegisterNode` has methods for generating the json through some `Annotations`. These are done in the `regmap` method by adding them to the `ElaborationArtefacts` object. Other protocols don't seem to have these annotations.

**Is there anyway to iterate over the "`regmap`" Register Fields post elaboration or during?**

I cannot just access the regmap as it's not really a val/var since it's a method. I can't quite figure out where this information is being stored. I don't really believe it's actually "storing" any information as much as it is simply creating the hardware to attach the specified logic to the RegisterNode based logic.

The JSON output is actually fine for me as I could just write a post processing script to convert JSON to my required formats, but I'm wondering if I can access this information OR if I could add a custom function call at the end. I cannot extend the `case class *RegisterNode`, but I'm not sure if it's possible to add custom functions to run at the end of the `regmap` method.

Here is something I threw together quickly:

```scala
//in *RegisterRouter.scala

def customregmap(customFunc: (RegField.Map*) => Unit, mapping: RegField.Map*) = {
  regmap(mapping:_*)
  customFunc(mapping:_*)
}

def regmap(mapping: RegField.Map*) = {
  //normal stuff
}
```

A user could then create a custom function to run and pass it to the regmap or to the RegisterRouter

```scala
def myFunc(mapping: RegField.Map*): Unit = {
  println("I'm doing my custom function for regmap!")
}

// ...

node.customregmap(myFunc, 
    0x0 -> coreControlRegFields,
    0x4 -> fdControlRegFields,
    0x8 -> fdControl2RegFields,    
  )
```

This is just a quick example I have. I believe what would be better, if something like this was possible, would be to have a `Seq` of functions that could be added to the `RegisterNode` that are ran at the end of the `regmap` method, similar to how `TLRegisterNode` currently works. So a user could add an arbitrary number and you still use the `regmap` call.

**Background (not directly part of question):**

I have a unified register script that I have built over the years in which I describe the registers for a particular IP. It works very similar to the RegField/node.regmap, except it obviously doesn't know about diplomacy and the like. It will generate the Verilog, but also a variety of files for DV (basic `defines  for simple verilog simulations and more complex `uvm_reg_block` defines also with the ability to describe multiple of the IPs for a subsystem all the way up to an SoC level). It will also print out C Header files for SW and Sphinx reStructuredText for documentation.

Diplomacy actually solves one of the main issues I've been dealing with so I'm obviously trying to push most of my newer designs to Chisel/Diplo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this by creating my own `RegisterNode` which is the same as the rocketchip RegisterNodes except that I use a different Elaboration Artifact to grab the info and store it for later.